# Web based progress bar reading from file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web-deployment

I have got 10 minute long script running called by php page after user clicking send button. I can output progress of the script to file, but how can I read it back to the page after user clicking send button. I do not want to open next page or keep refreshing current one. How would that be achieved?

Comment: Is it an upload? What's happening on the back end once they click the button?

Comment: It is not an upload, simply: server configuration scripts are running

Comment: use an ajax call to the server, that returns the contents of the progress file.  Start and stop an interval, that polls the server essentially.

Answer (score 1):

For the functionality you are trying to achieve, you need to work on a couple of things, so let's get started.

You need a button that calls the 10 minute long process. You already have it, so let's move on =)

If you want to stay on the same page, I would use Javascript to hide the button, and show the progress bar at 0%. If you wanted to be at a new page, I would use a Form, that when submitted, redirected me to the new page.

Either way, if you were redirected to a new page or you stayed, you need to keep track of who called the process. The reason is that when the user 'knocks' asking for the status, you know to which process their are referring to. The easiest way is to just store it in a Database with an ID, and keeping track of things. This ID can be obtained  with Javascript + AJAX (if you stayed), or with a server side response (if it was a redirect).

Now, you need to check the status of your server script. For that you would need an endpoint that receives the ID we generated in the previous step, and that when called returns the status of that process. You say you are using a Progress Bar, so I would also include a percentage in that call. An endpoint like example.com/my_process_status.php?process_id=10 that returns a JSON like {status: 'not_done', percentage: 15}

Now, with Javascript, you would call the endpoint to check the status using AJAX. If the status says that it is not ready, you just use `setTimeout()` to tell the code to check again in a couple of seconds and update the percentage of the Progress Bar.

Finally, when the endpoint tells you that the script is done, you stop calling `setTimeout()` and display in any way you find appropriate that it is finished (using Javascript).

I know it is a lot of work, but when it is all put together, things work nicely. If any of this isn't clear enough, I'll be happy to add some more info.

Comment: I don't undestand database step, why I would do that. My script is already writing data to process file, but it is not a problem to create next one with numbers inserted by my script. So can I just ready numbers from that file?

Comment: And I don't think I need to keep track who did called the process, it will always be one user at the time and it is going to be apache (www-data user). But maybe I am just missing something?

Comment: Oh, in that case, if it is just going to be 1 user, then things could be simplified. Instead of using a database to keep track of different calls by different users, you could use any method you like to retrieve the status of the process. As you say, you could read a file (although I'm not sure if it is such a good idea to be writting and reading a file simultaneously).

Answer (score -2):

With just php as a "SEVER SIDE LANGUAGE", you would need to poll the sever for the information using AJAX or (AKA) JAVASCRIPT ASYNCHRONOUS REQUESTS, to avoid reloading the page...

```
 var I = setInterval( function(){
    $.post( 'serverurl', function(data){
           //update progress with what is in data.
     });
},5000 );
```

On the php side of things, you would just read the file

```
  $progress = file_get_contents( 'file.txt' ); //or what have you
  echo $progress;   //or json_encode( $progress ); if you need more then a simple sting.
```

Fairly simple.

Buy the way, you can end the interval once you get to 100% by using the variable I ( in this example ), That way your not using up network traffic for no reason.

```
 clearInterval(I);
```

You could also store the Ajax request object in a variable and check it's status to make sure you don't have race conditions with your polling, but that is a post for another day.  For simple things like this where the return will likely only take a few seconds, it's probably not worth the work.

IF you use some thing like NODE js then that is a different story.

Comment: There is no AJAX in PHP - AJAX is used to make asynchronous calls via Javascript (from the client's browser). Not sure what the "with just php" portion is meant to convey.

Comment: No really? because Javascript and PHP never co-exist.  They are like bread and butter. or Jelly and PB

Comment: Coexisting and stating that AJAX is "just PHP" are two entirely different things. And no, you can have AJAX without PHP. Google "server side scripting" for a great example of what exists outside of PHP on the server side.

Comment: It was implying that with just php as a "Sever Side" language, you would need to use javascript to prevent page reloads.  As apposed to using something like Node.Js on the server side.  Let's split hair ok.

Comment: So clear up your answer. You have typos and a lack of elaboration.

Comment: I posted it like 10 seconds ago.

Comment: BTW, `var I = ` is unnecessary and a waste of memory. No sense in storing something that is never referenced.

Comment: BTW, it's not if you wish to end the interval, using clearInterval, at the 100%  mark, which saves way more network traffic then the minimal amount of memory it takes.

Comment: So post it? Lol... Are you seeing a trend here? Bad answers are bad.

Comment: Um, already did.  Sorry to break it to you Nate, but I have about 7 years php, and Javascript experience.  I sorta know what I am doing.  Just because I post an answer quickly, and update it after that, is not indication. Just a means to make sure It get's marked at the time instead of 15 -20 minutes later, I am Dyslexic after all.  So, yea that whole D and B thing, and grammar spelling, not exactly my thing.  But I suppose Patients isn't yours, is it?

Comment: Great! I have about 11 years of both as well! That's awesome and totally irrelevant. Thanks for sharing, though! If you need some help sometime let me know.

Comment: Sure, if you know anything about distributed Processing using RabitMq, Cassandra, Sphinx I'm all ears.  Or about migrating a production site into a DMZ that might help me a bit too.  Time for me to get back to writing my sFTP broker ( need to do some AES 256 on some credentials )

Comment: Of course I do - message queues have been around for a LONG time. Also, I'd suggest using AWS SQS as it's easier to scale and much easier to create redundancy for potential outages. Everything you listed is pretty easy, although I'm not sure why you just listed a few technologies and not your uses. PS, migrating a production site into a DMZ is silly, just use AWS with VPCs. There's no need to overcomplicate things. Oh, and your edit. sFTP is cake in PHP - should only take you a few minutes if you've got 7 years experience.

Comment: The sftp thing, is more about saving client credentials and implementing that into our products  then the actual, connecting ( which is easy using either the built in php library or "phpseclib" ) .  The DMZ unfortunately is compliance requirement, or rather a requirement a few of our clients ( or potential clients ) would like.  But anyway,.  ( We been using Rabbit and Sphinx in production for about 8 months btw )

Comment: A CIO that is coding? =D

Comment: Small company, I have only one Junior Developer. We don't ( technically ) have a CSO, but we have an outside contractor that has that role.  That said, we are soon to have about 90% killed off our competition, because of improvements over the last 3 years.  This is in a BtoB legal and compliance sector.  So we are small, but mighty.

Comment: I did ask about progress bar, not your experience.

Comment: We'll if other users on SO didn't attack and had some patience I wouldn't need to defend myself now would I.  Besides the solution I posted above is the way it is generally handled using PHP/HTML/JS, if you have other tools such as Node.js then there are other ways to do it.  But there is no way to pass data from the server to the client without it being requested first by the client,  client -> server -> client.